# How to return distinct rows with a specific condition?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table that looks like the below:

```
| FIELD_1 | FIELD_2 | FIELD_3 | FIELD_4 |
|---------|---------|---------|---------|
|   NULL  |   NULL  | potato  |  apple  |
|  basket |  fruit  | potato  |  apple  |
|   NULL  |   NULL  | potato  |  apple  |
|.........|.........|.........|.........|
```

`FIELD_3`, `FIELD_4` are always populated.

I want to go through this table and get the DISTINCT values of all fields, but for the rows for which `FIELD_1`, `FIELD_2` are populated to get only that set of fields instead of the NULLS.

For the above table that would return only:

```
|  basket |  fruit  | potato  |  apple  |
```

if that row was populated with only potato and apple in `FIELD_3`, `FIELD_4`.

I've done something similar in the past with an inner join where I would keep only the maximum row of `FIELD_1`, `FIELD_2` but now the fields are string and I want to check if the value is `NULL` or not.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . if I understand correctly, you want to filter out the `NULL` values in the first two columns when there are any other values.  But you want to keep them if there are not:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             count(field_1) over (partition by field_3, field_4) as cnt_field_1,
             count(field_2) over (partition by field_3, field_4) as cnt_field_2,
             row_number() over (partition by field_3, field_4, field_1, field_2) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1 and
      ( (field_1 is not null or field_2 is not null) or
        (cnt_field_1 = 0 and cnt_field_2 = 0)
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#standardSQL
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM `project.dataset.table`
WHERE NOT FIELD_1 IS NULL AND NOT FIELD_2 IS NULL
```

Comment: I accepted the above, but did not register it seems. I think in your solution if 'FIELD_1', 'FIELD_2' are NULL for a set of 'FIELD_3', 'FIELD_4' and there is no other not 'NULL' value for that set, it won't return the 'NULL' 'FIELD_1', 'FIELD_2' as I wanted. Gordon's answer seems to do that.

Comment: sure, no problem. that was not clear from the question though :o)